# I apologize (for having)/to sent you some correspondence that was not intended for you

Tags: word-choice, past-tense

Situation: I sent an email to the wrong addressee 2 days ago. He/she get the email and wrote me back that the correspondence was not his/hers. Now, I need to write him/her an apologetic answer.

> I apologize **for having** sent you some correspondence that was not intended for you.

Or

> I apologize **to** sent you some correspondence that was not intended for you.

Comment: The first option "I apologize for having sent you some correspondence that was not intended for you" is perfect (the second option is incorrect).

Comment: Is it correct to use the 1st option, when situation does not happen now, but 2 days ago?

Comment: @Zdenka yes. It is still correct if you sent the mail 2 days ago or more

Answer (score 1):

*Apologize for sending* is the most natural way of expressing this.

*Apologize for having sent* is possible, but native English speakers tend not to use the "past perfect" when the temporal relationships are clear without it.

*Apologize to sent* is not grammatical.

Comment: not "past perfect"... there is a non-finite perfective aspect of a present participle "having sent"

Comment: True. My observation still applies, but you're right this is a participial phrase, not a finite verb.